# Removing tmp file after return HttpResponse in django

Tags: python, django

I'm using the following django/python code to stream a file to the browser:

```
wrapper = FileWrapper(file(path))
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/plain')
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(path)
return response
```

Is there a way to delete the file after the reponse is returned? Using a callback function or something? 
I could just make a cron to delete all tmp files, but it would be neater if I could stream files and delete them as well from the same request.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a NamedTemporaryFile:

```
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile
def send_file(request):
    newfile = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.txt')
    # save your data to newfile.name
    wrapper = FileWrapper(newfile)
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=mime_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % os.path.basename(modelfile.name)
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(modelfile.name)
    return response
```

temporary file should be deleted once the newfile object is evicted.

Comment: `temporary file should be deleted once the newfile object is evicted`: is there a built-in mechanism to automatically delete `NamedTemporaryFile` instances?

Comment: if I'm correct, objects are destroyed by the garbage collector once all references to it are destroyed.
When you step out of the send_file function, there should be no more reference to the newfile object, hence it could be removed the next time the GC runs.
The destructor of NamedTemporaryFile states:

        def close(self):
            if not self.close_called:
                self.close_called = True
                self.file.close()
                self.unlink(self.name)

        def __del__(self):
            self.close()

Comment: fylb, you're right, but it's not guaranteed that the object will be garbage-collected and its __del__ method called. Who knows what the  garbage collector will do? Better to clean up manually periodically.

Answer (score 6):

For future references: 
I just had the case in which I couldn't use temp files for downloads. 
But I still needed to delete them after it; so here is how I did it (I really didn't want to rely on cron jobs or celery or wossnames, its a very small system and I wanted it to stay that way).

```
def plug_cleaning_into_stream(stream, filename):
    try:
        closer = getattr(stream, 'close')
        #define a new function that still uses the old one
        def new_closer():
            closer()
            os.remove(filename)
            #any cleaning you need added as well
        #substitute it to the old close() function
        setattr(stream, 'close', new_closer)
    except:
        raise
```

and then I just took the stream used for the response and plugged into it.

```
def send_file(request, filename):
    with io.open(filename, 'rb') as ready_file:
        plug_cleaning_into_stream(ready_file, filename)
        response = HttpResponse(ready_file.read(), content_type='application/force-download')
        # here all the rest of the heards settings
        # ...
        return response
```

I know this is quick and dirty but it works. I doubt it would be productive for a server with thousands of requests a second, but that's not my case here (max a few dozens a minute).

EDIT: Forgot to precise that I was dealing with very very big files that could not fit in memory during the download. So that is why I am using a `BufferedReader` (which is what is underneath `io.open()`)

Comment: very nice sir, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Mostly, we use periodic cron jobs for this.

Django already has one cron job to clean up lost sessions.  And you're already running it, right?

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-table

You want another command just like this one, in your application, that cleans up old files.

See this http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Also, you may not really be sending this file from Django.  Sometimes you can get better performance by creating the file in a directory used by Apache and redirecting to a URL so the file can be served by Apache for you.  Sometimes this is faster.  It doesn't handle the cleanup any better, however.

Comment: Instead of redirecting, you can use `mod xsendfile` with Apache, then it's one request and you can control file access.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add a view to delete this file and call it from *the client side* using an  asynchronous call (XMLHttpRequest). A variant of this would involve reporting back from the client on success so that the server can mark this file for deletion and have a periodic job clean it up.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea to me - there's no need for an additional message from the client to the server. Cleaning up the temp files periodically is much better.

Comment: @loevborg: The OP *asked* for alternatives. Hence. `I could just make a cron to delete all tmp files, but it would be neater ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is just using the regular python approach (very simple example):

```
# something generates a file at filepath

from subprocess import Popen

# open file
with open(filepath, "rb") as fid:
    filedata = fid.read()

# remove the file
p = Popen("rm %s" % filepath, shell=True)

# make response
response = HttpResponse(filedata, content-type="text/plain")

return response
```

Comment: yikes that has so many security holes and escaping problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3.7 , Django 2.2.5**

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from django.http import HttpResponse
with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.csv', mode='r+', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write('\uFEFF')  # BOM
    f.write('sth you want')

    # ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#examples
    f.seek(0)
    data=f.read()

    response = HttpResponse(data, content_type="text/plain")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=export.csv'
```

Comment: please provide some explanation for your answer and avoid posting code only answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve that by try / finally:

```
try:
    HttpResponse(...) / FileResponse(...)
finally:
    os.remove(tmp_file) / shutil.rmtree(path_to_tmp_file)
```